# Optional calls in GoMock

Tags: go, mocking, gomock

I want to use GoMock to test some code, without coupling my tests too tightly to the actual implementation of the thing under test. But GoMock seems to require that I be able to say in advance exactly what calls the code under test will make, even if that's not part of the contract I'm trying to test. Is there a way around this?

For example, say I'm testing some validation logic, where the code under test is required to take a `Widget` named `mockedObject`, and return false if either `mockedObject.CheckConditionA()` or `mockedObject.CheckCondition1()` returns false, and to return true otherwise. One correct implementation is:

```
func UnderTest(mockedObject *Widget) bool {
    if !mockedObject.CheckConditionA() {
        return false
    }
    return mockedObject.CheckCondition1()
}
```

Another is:

```
func UnderTest(mockedObject *Widget) bool {
    if !mockedObject.CheckCondition1() {
        return false
    }
    return mockedObject.CheckConditionA()
}
```

A third is:

```
func UnderTest(mockedObject *Widget) bool {
    cA := mockedObject.CheckConditionA()
    c1 := mockedObject.CheckCondition1()
    return cA && c1
}
```

And a fourth is:

```
func UnderTest(mockedObject *Widget) bool {
    if TodayIsAnAlternateTuesday() {
        return mockedObject.CheckCondition1() && mockedObject.CheckConditionA()
    }
    return mockedObject.CheckConditionA() && mockedObject.CheckCondition1()
}
```

My test shouldn't have to care which of these is being used; I just want to check that the contract is fulfilled.

How do I set up the mocks for a test like this, where the code under test is allowed but not required to call a method?

For the test for the case where `CheckConditionA()` will return false, I need to set up something like `mockedObject.EXPECT().CheckConditionA().Return(false)`. But some of these implementations will also require a `mockedObject.EXPECT().CheckCondition1().Return(true)` in order to work, or my test will fail due to unexpected calls. On the other hand, some will fail if I provide that `EXPECT`, due to missing calls.

Does GoMock just not support writing this kind of test? If not, what else could I be using that would let me test this function without constructing a real live `Widget`?

Answer (score 5):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3600781) gets at the problem in a general context, and following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3601097) to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1107240) shows that in this case you do not want **Mocks**; you actually want **Stubs**, which are mocks that don't insist on being called but if called will return the right things.

The GoMock README actually has [a whole section on building stubs instead of mocks](https://github.com/golang/mock#building-stubs), the upshot of which is that you need to use `AnyTimes()` at the end of the `EXPECT()` call chain to make it optional.

```
mockedObject.EXPECT().CheckConditionA().Return(false)
mockedObject.EXPECT().CheckCondition1().Return(true).AnyTimes()
```

Unfortunately, that README section contains exactly one title and two code examples, with no text about what a stub is or why someone would want one, which means if your first exposure to mock-based testing is through GoMock you are not going to figure this out very quickly. The main GoMock docs have [a one-line description of AnyTimes()](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/mock/gomock#Call.AnyTimes), but nothing about stubs as a concept. (Or about mocks as a concept for that matter; they just sort of assume you've heard of them.)